# Spring @RequestParam is not working with HTML FormData

Tags: spring, form-data

I wanna do a file upload using angularjs as the front-end, and Spring Rest as the back-end. Here is my front-end code:

```
var data = evt.target.result;
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.set("fileId", 1);
        formData.set("file", data);

        $http({method: "POST", url: "/file", data: formData, headers : {"Content-Type": undefined}, transformRequest: angular.identity}).success(function() {
            console.log("hi");
        }).error(function(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
        });
```

And here is my back-end code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

I think my code should be working, but in fact, I keep getting error 400 saying that **"Required request part 'file' is not present"**.

any ideas? Thanks.

Here is the data from the firebug:

```
-----------------------------5045635351933894389797998578
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileId"

1
-----------------------------5045635351933894389797998578
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

%PDF-1.7
%Ã¤Ã£ÃÃ’
4 0 obj
<</Type/XObject
/Subtype/Form
/FormType 1
/Matrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]
/BBox[0 0 612 792]
/Resources<</ExtGState<</GS0 5 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/ImageC]/Properties<</MC0 6 0 R>>/XObject<</Im0 7 0
 R>>>>/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 343>>
stream
HÂ‰Â”Â“ÃNÃƒ0Â†Ã¯y
Â¿@SÃ‡Â±Â“Ã¸ÃŠÂ†&;Ã°
-----------------------------5045635351933894389797998578--
```

We can clearly see the param name, one is fileId and the other is file.

Comment: This post here [multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs) presents a slightly different version of the front-end code you should have using angularjs...

Comment: instead of formData.set try formData.append

Comment: I use formData.append before I try formData.set @RameshKotha

Comment: my angularjs front-end is working, the data reach the server successfully, so I dont think something wrong with the front-end code. @Filip

Comment: Do you have MultipartResover configured?

Comment: @jny Yes I have MultipartResolver configured.

Comment: Can you please share the "request payload", it's registered by Chrome's Network tab of Developer Tools, or the equivalent of any other browser that supports dev tooling...

Comment: Thanks for helping : ) I solved @Filip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sovled it! The error is that I tried to upload a file's data, not the whole file, which include data, file name and other useful attributes. The previous code is like the following:

```
var data = evt.target.result;
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("fileId", 1);
        formData.append("file", data);
```

I change it into the following:

```
var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("fileId", 1);
        formData.append("file", file);
```

file variable reference to the HTML5 file object, while the previous one reference to the file's binary data.